# What is the <leader> in a .vimrc file?

Tags: vim, macvim

I see `<leader>` in many `.vimrc` files, and I am wondering what does it mean?

What is it used for?

Just a general overview of the purpose and usage would be great.

Comment: I'm coming to realize that I think the key understanding is that by using `<leader>` in your keyboard shortcuts you are effectively creating a namespace so that your custom shortcuts don't step on built-in vim behavior.  See @Pete Schlette's answer below for more.

Comment: If you want to check what your `<leader>` is, use `:echo mapleader` or `:let mapleader`. If undefined, then it will use the default, which is a backslash `"\"`

Comment: Is there any alternative to `:let mapleader` ? I'm using a vscodevim plugin which doesn't have "let" implemented yet.

Answer (score 1215, accepted):

The [`<Leader>`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3CLeader%3E) key is mapped to <kbd>\</kbd> by default.  So if you have a map of `<Leader>t`, you can execute it by default with <kbd>\</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>.  For more detail or re-assigning it using the `mapleader` variable, see

:help leader

```
To define a mapping which uses the "mapleader" variable, the special string
"<Leader>" can be used.  It is replaced with the string value of "mapleader".
If "mapleader" is not set or empty, a backslash is used instead.  
Example:
    :map <Leader>A  oanother line <Esc>
Works like:
    :map \A  oanother line <Esc>
But after:
    :let mapleader = ","
It works like:
    :map ,A  oanother line <Esc>

Note that the value of "mapleader" is used at the moment the mapping is
defined.  Changing "mapleader" after that has no effect for already defined
mappings.
```

Comment: The change to `,` is a good one. Much easier to reach than `\\ `, and who uses `,` in vim anyway?

Comment: Thanks for the help, this definitely points me in the right direction.

Comment: @Gabe Moothart. :h , gives you "Repeat latest f, t, F or T in opposite direction [count] times."


It is quite convenient.

Comment: There's also a a good writeup here: http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/09/coming-home-to-vim/#using-the-leader

Comment: @sehe Yes you're right, not sure how I missed that given it's right at the top! I've deleted my comment.

Comment: I'm liking space `(' ')` as a leader key because I can hit it with either hand, making the follow up key (whether it's on the left or right side of the keyboard) equally quick to trigger afterward. Having a leader key that itself is only on one side of the keyboard makes hitting follow up keys on the same side of the keyboard feel slightly more cumbersome. Nitpicky, I know. :)

Comment: I don't see how this answers what is the purpose of the leader or why you would want to use it.

Comment: @User It's basically a personal namespace for commands. You know won't be used by plugins or newer versions of vim.

Comment: @jefflunt My right thumb is already week because I've never used it for typing. So I only use left thumb for hitting spaces. That space leader key does not provide the same benefit to me, I guess.

Comment: As a touch typer, I have never used my thumb for anything other than space, so space seems to be the perfect leader key for me.

Comment: @GabeMoothart `,` and `;` are very frequently used for in-line navigation in normal mode with `f` or `t`.

Answer (score 327):

Be aware that when you do press your `<leader>` key **you have only 1000ms** or **1 second** (by default) **to enter the command** following it.

This is exacerbated because there is *no* visual feedback (by default) that you have pressed your `<leader>` key and vim is awaiting the command; and so there is also no visual way to know when this time out has happened.

If you add `set showcmd` to your `vimrc` then you will see your `<leader>` key appear in the bottom right hand corner of vim (to the left of the cursor location) and perhaps more importantly you will see it *disappear* when the time out happens.

The length of the timeout can also be set in your `vimrc`, see [`:help timeoutlen`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27timeoutlen%27) for more information.

Comment: « :set showcmd » shows the current command hence the leader key the time it is active.

Comment: To the lack of feedback, while by default there is no visual feedback, it appears that vim will sound a system bell if it doesn't receive a command in the 1000ms after you press `<leader>`.

Answer (score 142):

The "Leader key" is a way of extending the power of VIM's shortcuts by using sequences of keys to perform a command. The default leader key is backslash. Therefore, if you have a map of <Leader>Q, you can perform that action by typing \Q.

Comment: @ArnoldRoa Whenever vim commands are listed, the syntax `ggdG` means to press those four keys sequentially. A syntax like `<C-w><C-j>` means to press CTRL+w, followed by CTRL+j.

Comment: @gobernador I can't find what is `<A-i>` for example. I assume it's ALT... ?

Answer (score 136):

Vim's `<leader>` key is a way of creating a namespace for commands you want to define. Vim already maps most keys and combinations of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + (some key), so `<leader>(some key)` is where you (or plugins) can add custom behavior.

For example, if you find yourself frequently deleting exactly 3 words and 7 characters, you might find it convenient to map a command via `nmap <leader>d 3dw7x` so that pressing the leader key followed by d will delete 3 words and 7 characters. Because it uses the leader key as a prefix, you can be (relatively) assured that you're not stomping on any pre-existing behavior.

The default key for `<leader>` is `\`, but you can use the command `:let mapleader = ","` to remap it to another key (`,` in this case).

[Usevim's page on the leader key](https://medium.com/usevim/vim-101-what-is-the-leader-key-f2f5c1fa610f) has more information.

Answer (score 19):

The default leader key is backslash(<kbd>\</kbd>). It's used in bindings as a chord with other keystrokes.