# Is there an HTML escape paste mode for vim?

Tags: vim

I'm using vim to maintain a weblog of what I do through the day (what commands I used to generate output, etc..), and sometimes I need to copy-paste strings that have special html characters in them. Is there a way to make an "html-paste" mode that will (for instance) convert < to &lt;?

Comment: vim-unimpaired - https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired#unimpairedvim

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few small functions [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/HTML_entities) if someone feels like modifying them to accept a range, then provide a mapping which passes the `[` and `]` marks to act on the last pasted text.

---

Actually, after looking a bit, you don't need to modify the functions from the vim tip at all.  If a function doesn't explicitly pass the `range` option, the function is called once for each line of the given range.  This means that all you need to do is call the function with a range.

A couple useful examples are below.  The first calls HtmlEscape() for each line in the last pasted text, the second does the same but for each line in a visually selected block.  Add this to your `.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <Leader>h :'[,']call HtmlEscape()<CR>
vnoremap <Leader>h :call HtmlEscape()<CR>

function HtmlEscape()
  silent s/&/\&amp;/eg
  silent s/</\&lt;/eg
  silent s/>/\&gt;/eg
endfunction
```

Obviously if you want more things replaced you'd have to add them; there are many on the linked wiki page.

Comment: Works great ! Additionally a litte explanation of <Leader> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764263/what-is-the-leader-in-a-vimrc-file

Comment: Just curious, Why `\&` instead of `&` in the substitution?

Comment: @rox See `:help sub-replace-special`.  It all depends on what your vim settings are, but by default `&` gets substituted with the entire matched string.

Answer (score 7):

For simple XML encoding I use Tim Pope's [unimpaired.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1590).

- `[x` followed by a motion
- visually select the text then `[x`
- `[xx` to encode the current line

To encode the just pasted text:

```
`[[x`]
```

Explanation:

- `` `[ `` and `` `] `` are marks set by the boundaries of a change or a yank. `` `[ `` at the beginning and `` `] `` at the end.
- First move to the start of the just pasted text with `` `[ ``
- Next execute `[x` to encode the following motion
- By using `` `] `` the motion will be all the text between the current cursor location to the end of the pasted text.

Optionally you can wrap this up into a mapping

```
nmap <leader>x `[[x`]
```

More information:

```
:h mark-motion
:h `[
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a mapping that will convert register value and then paste it:

```
python import xmlrpclib, vim
function! EscapeHTML(str)
    try " Force any error to be an exception "
        let d={}
        python vim.eval("extend(d, {'xml': '"+xmlrpclib.escape(vim.eval("a:str")).replace("'", "''")+"'})")
        return d.xml
    endtry
endfunction
function! s:PasteHTML()
    return "\"=EscapeHTML(getreg(".string(v:register)."))\np"
endfunction
nnoremap <expr> ,p <SID>PasteHTML()
```

Requires vim with python support and python installed. `xmlrpclib` packages comes with python. If you don't want python, replace EscapeHTML function. With this script `,p` will work just as `p` except for converting its input.