# What is the difference between the mapleaders <Leader> and <leader> in Vim scripts?

Tags: vim

Wondering if there is a difference between

```
map <Leader>f x
```

and

```
map <leader>f x
```

in Vim scripts?

Why the variants?

Answer (score 7):

There is no difference—it's just case-insensitive. This works too:

```
map <lEaDeR>f x
```

The documentation uses `<Leader>`, so it's probably best to do the same.

Comment: This would also explain that `<Esc>` and `<esc>` produce the same result. :)

Answer (score 0):

No difference ... they are same.

Check this link [What is the <leader> in a .vimrc file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764263/what-is-the-leader-in-a-vimrc-file)