# Easy way to copy the word under the caret in Vim

Tags: vim, copy-paste, vi

I am trying to find an easy way to copy the word that the caret is currently on top of. 
I know that I can select to the front of the word: press <kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> <kbd>y</kbd>. 
But this seems crazy, I can simply press * above a word to search for it, surely there is a better way to copy the word. Maybe even in a single key press?

Comment: You can map a key to `yiw`. eg. `nmap <leader>w yiw`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use <kbd>y</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd> (Yank In Word). Though it is just as many keystrokes. If you are at the beginning of the word you can drop the <kbd>i</kbd> and use either <kbd>y</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd> or <kbd>y</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd>.

Alternatively you can map the command to a key any way you like. For example, you could put this in your vimrc file:

```
nmap <F8> yiw
```

The <kbd>F8</kbd> key is right near the  <kbd>*</kbd> key so it would be easy to remember that it acts similar to the  <kbd>*</kbd> word highlight. This would be a single key to yank the word.

UPDATE:

Satoru.Logic's comment is definitely a good way to go. If you are not sure what `<leader>` means, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764263/what-is-the-leader-in-a-vimrc-file) post.

Comment: `yiw` moves the cursor to the beginning of the word, which wasn't asked for.

Comment: @rfabbri: If you know a way to prevent it, feel free to edit my answer. I'm not aware of any way to do it without the cursor moving after the yank completes.