# Vim, do an operation after going to a specific line

Tags: command-line, line, vim

In Vim you can travel to a given line by entering vim's command mode and enter that given line's number there.

I want a specific operation to always take place after moving to a line number in that way.
How do I do that?

This is intended to adjust the screen, by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you enter either of the following in order to jump to line #123 in command mode:

```
123G
123gg
```

You just need to find a key to map your new command to (I would recommend using the [leader key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1764336/44562), which was created for exactly this purpose):

```
noremap <LEADER>G G:YourCommand<CR>
noremap <LEADER>gg gg:YourCommand<CR>
" Now you can type 123\G instead (assuming you
" have not changed your default leader key)
```

Or, you can overwrite the existing key (not recommended, as it might mess up other scripts):

```
noremap G G:YourCommand<CR>
noremap gg gg:YourCommand<CR>
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped. 'map G Gsk' now means my screen always gets adjusted automatically when moving using G.