# Passing argument to vim map

Tags: vi, vim

```
 (A) Upper and lower limits on numeric data.
 (B) Passwords to prohibit unauthorised access to files.
 (C) Data dictionary to keep the data
 (D) Data dictionary to find last access of data
```

I want to copy the **(A)** to buffer-**a**, **(B)** to buffer-**b**, etc.

I want to use the key **s** for this purpose. **sa** should copy the current line
 to buffer-**a**, **sb** to buffer-**b**, etc.

I wrote the code `:map s "ayy` to map **s** to copy the current line to buffer-**a**

But I don't have any idea how to pass the buffer name. (The character typing after **s**.)

UPDATE: Want to copy to register, not buffer!!

Comment: There is a nice series of [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) episodes that cover register usage: [The copy/paste series - a retrospective](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/simple-operations-using-the-default-register/)

Answer (score 5):

- What you are trying to do is coping lines to **register**, not **buffer**, your question is pretty confusing. they are two totally different things in vim.
- try to find another key-combination for your mapping. `s` is so useful. Maybe you could try `<leader>sX`(X here is the register name)

Your requirement could be achieved by using `<expr> mapping`, this mapping would do it for you:

```
nnoremap <expr> <leader>s '"'.nr2char(getchar()).'Y'
```

If you press `<leader>sa` the line under your cursor will be yanked to register `a`. `<leader>sm` will yank current line to register `m` and so on.

default `<leader>` is <kbd>\</kbd>, `:h leader` for details.

Comment: That's pretty nifty (using `getchar()` in a mapping)

Comment: What is the `<leader>` means? Didn't understand from the help :)

Comment: @HabeebPerwad does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764263/what-is-the-leader-in-a-vimrc-file

Comment: how would you copy something selected in visual mode, not all the line. I guess it's not like '"'.nr2char(getchar()).'y'

Comment: @ArturDumchev you need two changes for that, 1. `nnoremap -> vnoremap` 2. `'Y' -> 'y'`

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to Kent's approach with `getchar()` is to restructure your mapping to `"as` instead of `sa`. That would also be in line with Vim's built in command scheme (where `"ayy` is yanking to register a). With that, you'll get the parsing of the register for free, in the form of the `v:register` variable.

Your `s` mapping would then be just `:nnoremap s yy`; the register part would automatically be passed to `yy`. For a more complex mapping, you could use:

```
:nnoremap <silent> s :execute '"' . v:register . 'yy'<CR>
```

Comment: Actually `yy` is just for demo purpose. I am actually using bit bigger like `03wy$`...

Comment: That's what I mean with "complex mapping".