# git config rebase.abbreviateCommands

Tags: git, git-config

I'd like to enable `rebase.abbreviateCommands`.  I added the lines below to my git  file (~/.gitconfig), saved, opened a new terminal, cd to a git repo, then attempted a `git rebase -i HEAD~`, and I still "pick" instead of "p".  I confirmed git is using this file by removing configurations and observing changes, and by running `git config -l`.

```
[rebase]
        abbreviateCommands = true
```

Doc:
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config
(search for abbreviateCommands)

Comment: Not directly related to the answer (which is almost certainly "your Git is older"), but: why do you care how long the word in the generated file is? I'm curious since I do not quite understand why they added this "abbreviateCommands" feature in the first place. Might be because I use vi/vim and just type `cw` to change any given command, so `cwe<ESC>` is no more work regardless of whether it says `pick` or `p`...

Comment: @torek That works.  I do use vim, but I mapped c to something else (time to undo that).  I've been typing `dwie<SPACE><ESC>`, when I felt `re` would be much more comfortable.

Comment: vim has the search-for-unused-command-sequence beat all hollow, vs original vi :-) (I started making use of `:map <Leader>` a while back. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/1764263/1256452.)

Comment: @torek Until I get 2.16, I'll use this: `map <LEADER>e :s/pick/e <CR>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rebase.abbreviateCommands` was new in Git version 2.16.0.  What Git version are you running?

Comment: 2.11.0.  I'm on Debian :\

Answer (score 3):

If you do use `rebase.abbreviateCommands`, consider the latest With Git 2.27 (Q2 2020):
"`git rebase`" with the merge backend did not work well when the `rebase.abbreviateCommands` configuration was set before 2.27.

See [commit de9f1d3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/de9f1d3ef45ec885339d04f9e34293eb2de8605d), [commit 68e7090](https://github.com/git/git/commit/68e7090f31b4d4f2c7b9a25240af61149fbebb5c) (30 Mar 2020) by [Alban Gruin (`agrn`)](https://github.com/agrn).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f72e067](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f72e06703b14b3bccaaeee97ac82257dff67749c), 22 Apr 2020)</sup>

> ### [`sequencer`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/68e7090f31b4d4f2c7b9a25240af61149fbebb5c): don't abbreviate a command if it doesn't have a short form
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Alban Gruin</sup>
>
> When the sequencer is requested to abbreviate commands, it will replace those that do not have a short form (eg. `noop`) by a comment mark.
>   `noop` serves no purpose, except when fast-forwarding (ie. by running `git rebase`).
>
> Removing it will break this command when `rebase.abbreviateCommands` is set to `true`.
>
> Teach `todo_list_to_strbuf()` to check if a command has an actual short form, and to ignore it if not.